# Selenium and PhantomJS with C#. Wait problems

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs

I've been teaching myself how to use Selenium and Phantom JS but I've arrived to a bind.

I haven't been able to implement a wait despite numerous attempts.

Here is my main attempt:

Driverwait:

```
_wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));
```

Url:

```
private const string FACTBOOKURL = 
    "https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/index.html";
```

Method:

```
public static string GetValueFromKeyAndCountry(string key, string country, string category)
{
    string res = string.Empty;
    IWebElement dropDownCountryList = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@name='selecter_links']"));
    SelectElement countryList = new SelectElement(dropDownCountryList);
    countryList.SelectByText(country);
    IWebElement pE = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//h2[@sectiontitle='" + category + "']"));
    pE.Click();
    IWebElement mainElement = pE.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(.,'" + key + "')]"));
    Console.WriteLine("-----LOG: \n-Tagname: " + mainElement.TagName + " \n-Attribute: " + mainElement.GetAttribute("class") + " \n-Text: " + mainElement.Text);
    IWebElement parent = GetParent(mainElement);
    Console.WriteLine("-----LOG: \n-Tagname: " + parent.TagName + " \n-Attribute: " + parent.GetAttribute("class") + " \n-Text: " + parent.Text);
   //------ This is the main part. I wait for the element to be found and I return its contents. 
    _wait.Until((d) =>
                        {
                            return parent.FindElement(By.XPath(".//span[@class='category_data']"));
                        });
    mainElement = parent.FindElement(By.XPath(".//span[@class='category_data']"));
    return mainElement.Text;
}
```

Method call:

```
string president = 
   PropertyManager.GetValueFromKeyAndCountry("head of government: ", "Colombia", "Government");
```

Structure of the webpage:

[image]

I don't want to use an implicit wait. I wish to wait for the element to be available but this code seems incorrect. I can't tell what I am missing.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, or even an alternative solution (that isn't an implicit wait of course).